# Se me borro mi proyecto de mi app en Android Studio, como lo recupero?

Tags: android-studio, app, google-play, aplicación-movil

Ojala y puedan ayudarme con esto.

Mi proyecto de mi aplicación móvil se me borro de la computadora y no puedo recuperarlo para actualizar la app, pero esta publicada en la play store, existe alguna manera de poder descargar la versión publicada y trabajar sobre esa en Android Studio?

Comment: Creo que podrías hacer ingeniería inversa al apk aún así, lo más importante es que la firma sea la misma siempre. Así que si perdiste el keystore lo tienes complicado.